# To prove $V$ Is not a vector space and my attempt

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be set of all pairs $(x,y)$ of real numbers and $\Bbb F$ be the field of real numbers.
Define

$c(x,y)$ = $( |c|x ,  |c|y)$

Addition defined as usual but it is not main concern here

What I have done is that

Case 1 - $c$ is positive

$c(x,y)$ = $( |c|x ,  |c|y)$ = $(cx,cy)$

Case 2

$c$ is negative

$c(x,y)$ = $( |-c|x ,  |-c|y)$ = $(cx,cy)$

My conclusion is that result is same for both cases. But it should be unique. So It is not a vector space. Am I correct ?

Comment: What is V here?

Comment: @Dylan Fixed the question

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts that might be helpful are:  First, this type of multiplication violates at least one of the properties stated in the definition of a vector space.

Second, if this operation was allow, you could start with a zero vector and get total nonsense, such as (0,0) = (-1+1)(x,y) = (x,y) + (x,y) = 2(x,y).  The only time that c(x,y) = ( |c|x ,  |c|y) could be allowed is when the only vector in the space is the zero vector.